# C# / Winforms: Always keep a form focusable

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, .net-2.0

I want to implement a help-form into my app, which can get the focus, *even* if a dialog is shown. At the moment i dispose the actual instance of my help if it can't get focused, but i dont think thats the right way. So i want to ask, if theres a option to show a form, seperated from the logic of my main-application.

Things i tried:

- calling as a AppDomain ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173139%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))
- putting the help into seperate app and call it as a process

In both ways, the help(-form) can't get the focus back, when a dialog was called.

I dont want to use the help provided with C#, because i need to show the help(-pages) inside the application.

Thanks

PS: I'm using .Net 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by creating an STA thread and using `Application.Run()` to display the form from that separate thread. `Application.Run()` will create a separate *Message Pump* for the other form; this is what keeps it separate.

If you do that, you have to be VERY CAREFUL when communicating between the forms. You will need to use `Control.Invoke()` or some other inter-thread mechanism to call UI-changing methods on the second form from the first form (and vice-versa).

But if you do this, then the first form can be showing a modal dialog, and the second form will still be focusable.

Note that the second window may be behind the first window because there will be no way to specify the relative Z-order between them.

Showing the second form can be done like this:

```
private static void ShowIndependentForm()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(ShowIndependentFormImpl);
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
}

private static void ShowIndependentFormImpl()
{
    Application.Run(new Form2());
}
```

You can just call ShowIndependentForm() where appropriate; probably from the main form after you have created it, but my test code in `Main()` looks like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    ShowIndependentForm();
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

**Important**

Because the second form has its own message pump, closing the first form will NOT close the program unless you set `Thread.IsBackground` to true. If you don't, you will have to explicitly close the second form (via calling a method in the second form using `Control.Invoke()` or some other way) when the first form closes if you want the program to close automatically.

Comment: Setting Thread.IsBackground = true is enough to avoid the close-the-program hassle.  You probably ought to say something about the Z-order problem, the help window can show up behind another window.

Comment: Thanks! I had some trouble with the threading, but now it works like wanted :)

Comment: Ah, the IsBackground is interesting. I wrote a seperate Dispose method, but this seems the better way.